# Choice of embeddable browser

Tags: linux, awesomium, chromium-embedded, embedded-browser, berkelium

I'm starting to desing С++ Linux program with Qt-based GUI. Now I'm looking for all possible embeddable browsers which I will be able to use in my project. I know about Chromium-based solutions - Berkelium, CEF and Awesomium. Anything else?

Also it will be nice to hear some comments about practical use of such systems.

Answer (score 0):

What about using QtWebKit that's already in your Qt-based system? [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org) may be of interest. It probably has a way to use a C++ backend, as the toolkit already works with Ruby, Python, and PHP. However, I think they are primarily a packaged version of CEF for dynamic languages.